# Android - Avoid the alarm triggering when user changes date/time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an app that sends periodic alarms every day of the week, through the method `setRepeating` from `AlarmManager`:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(INTENT_TAG_ALERT_ID, lastAlertId.getId()+"");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idRandom, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cDate.getTimeInMillis(), ((AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY)*7), pendingIntent);
```

And then get the alarm on my `AlarmReceiver` defined on manifest as a Receiver:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".manager.alarm.AlarmReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
```

The problem is when the user changes the Date/Time from his phone for a day or 2 in the future, I receive several calls from the receiver (depending on the number of days chosen). Since I use a `setRepeating` method I can't validate if the alarm was sent at the right time.

I know this is normal procedure as described on here: 
["A trigger time. If the trigger time you specify is in the past, the alarm triggers immediately."](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), but I want to prevent it.

I thought of putting a listener to know when the user changes the date and time of his phone, to unschedule all the alarms and then schedule them again, as you can see bellow:

```
public class DateTimeChangedBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)) {
        AlarmScheduler.unscheduleAllAlarms();
        //and then
        AlarmScheduler.scheduleAllAlarms();
    }
}
}
```

And the manifest:

```
        <receiver android:name=".manager.alarm.DateTimeChangedBroadcastReceiver"
        android:priority="1000">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_TIME"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

But in this solution, the receiver of time changes come after the receiver from the alarm, so it doesn't serve me much...

Is there a way to choose the order of my receivers?

Is there a better way to do this?

I also though of putting a listener to clock time, to store it. if the user changes the hour I should only validate the difference... but I believe I can get a better way to do this (preferentially not involving another listener on the app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an ideal solution, more like a workaround, but it does the trick...

Since I couldn't find a way to order my receivers, I was forced to find a solution inside Alarm Receiver... so I created a method to know if Alarm is valid or not... it's a bit large, but it deals with daily and periodic alarms...
Here's the code:

```
    public boolean isReceiveAlarmValid (AlertData alertData, AlarmData alarmData){
    if ((alertData != null) && (alarmData != null)) {

        Calendar caInitialDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        //Set beginning of counting to alarm starting date
        caInitialDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, alarmData.getTimeAlarmYear());
        caInitialDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, (alarmData.getTimeAlarmMonth()) - 1);
        caInitialDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, alarmData.getTimeAlarmDay());
        caInitialDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmData.getTimeAlarmHour());
        caInitialDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmData.getTimeAlarmMinute());
        caInitialDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, alarmData.getTimeAlarmSeconds());

        caInitialDate.add(Calendar.MINUTE, alertData.getRescheduleCounter() * GeneralData.getInstance().getAlarmReschedulePeriodicity());

        alarmData.setTimeAlarm(GlobalFunctions.generateStringDateFromCalendar(caInitialDate));

        //Initialization
        int sizeAux = 7;
        String auxDateComp = "";
        String auxDate = null;
        String[] auxDateArray = new String[7];

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int todayDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        if (Consts.FREQUENCY_ONCE == alarmData.getAlarmFrequency()) {
            //Alarm Once
            auxDate = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%04d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmYear()) + "-" +
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmMonth()) + "-" +
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmDay()) + " " +
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmHour()) + ":" +
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmMinute()) + ":00";

            auxDateComp = auxDate;

        } else if (Consts.FREQUENCY_DAILY == alarmData.getAlarmFrequency()) {
            //Alarm Daily

            //Cycle to know what a specific day we are gonna compare on the week
            dayCicle:
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

                int auxDay = todayDay + i;
                if (auxDay > 7)
                    auxDay = auxDay - 7;

                auxDateArray = new String[7];

                if (((alarmData.isRepeatMonday()) && (auxDay == dayMon)) ||
                        ((alarmData.isRepeatTuesday()) && (auxDay == dayTue)) ||
                        ((alarmData.isRepeatWednesday()) && (auxDay == dayWed)) ||
                        ((alarmData.isRepeatThursday()) && (auxDay == dayThu)) ||
                        ((alarmData.isRepeatFriday()) && (auxDay == dayFri)) ||
                        ((alarmData.isRepeatSaturday()) && (auxDay == daySat)) ||
                        ((alarmData.isRepeatSunday()) && (auxDay == daySun))) {

                    int dayPeriodic = auxDay;
                    boolean[] isRepeatElements = new boolean[7];
                    isRepeatElements[Consts.ANDROID_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_SUNDAY] = alarmData.isRepeatSunday();
                    isRepeatElements[Consts.ANDROID_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_MONDAY] = alarmData.isRepeatMonday();
                    isRepeatElements[Consts.ANDROID_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_TUESDAY] = alarmData.isRepeatTuesday();
                    isRepeatElements[Consts.ANDROID_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_WEDNESDAY] = alarmData.isRepeatWednesday();
                    isRepeatElements[Consts.ANDROID_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_THURSDAY] = alarmData.isRepeatThursday();
                    isRepeatElements[Consts.ANDROID_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_FRIDAY] = alarmData.isRepeatFriday();
                    isRepeatElements[Consts.ANDROID_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_SATURDAY] = alarmData.isRepeatSaturday();


                    int daysCount = i;

                    Calendar caTimeStartAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar caNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                    //Set beginning of counting to alarm starting date
                    caTimeStartAlarm.set(Calendar.YEAR, alarmData.getTimeAlarmYear());
                    caTimeStartAlarm.set(Calendar.MONTH, (alarmData.getTimeAlarmMonth()) - 1);
                    caTimeStartAlarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, alarmData.getTimeAlarmDay());
                    caTimeStartAlarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmData.getTimeAlarmHour());
                    caTimeStartAlarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmData.getTimeAlarmMinute());
                    caTimeStartAlarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, alarmData.getTimeAlarmSeconds());

                    Calendar calInitial = null;

                    //If time now is after starting time, the base date is the now date
                    if (caTimeStartAlarm.after(caNow)) {
                        calInitial = (Calendar) caTimeStartAlarm.clone();
                    } else {
                        calInitial = (Calendar) caNow.clone();
                    }


                    //cycle that increase days adding to next alarms
                    for (int z = 0; z < 7; z++) {

                        //only chosen periodic daily days
                        if (isRepeatElements[dayPeriodic - 1]) {

                            Calendar caPossibleAlarm = (Calendar) calInitial.clone();
                            //Add daily day
                            caPossibleAlarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, caPossibleAlarm.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + daysCount);
                            caPossibleAlarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmData.getTimeAlarmHour());
                            caPossibleAlarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmData.getTimeAlarmMinute());
                            caPossibleAlarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, alarmData.getTimeAlarmSeconds());

                            //add a few seconds of margin
                            caPossibleAlarm.add(Calendar.SECOND, ALARM_RECEIVE_TIME_MARGIN);

                            if (!(calInitial.after(caPossibleAlarm))) {
                                //If now is not after (before or equal) next alarm, then it can show

                                String yearAux = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%04d", caPossibleAlarm.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                                String monthAux = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", caPossibleAlarm.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
                                String dayAux = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", caPossibleAlarm.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                                auxDate = yearAux + "-" + monthAux + "-" + dayAux + " " +
                                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmHour()) + ":" +
                                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmMinute()) + ":00";

                                auxDateComp = auxDate;

                            }

                        }

                        if ("".equals(auxDateComp)) {

                            dayPeriodic++;
                            if (dayPeriodic > 7)
                                dayPeriodic = dayPeriodic - 7;

                            daysCount++;
                        } else {
                            //it has found a value
                            break dayCicle;
                        }
                    }

                    break dayCicle;

                }

            }

        } else {
            //Periodic Weekly / Monthly

            auxDate = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%04d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmYear()) + "-" +
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmMonth()) + "-" +
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmDay()) + " " +
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmHour()) + ":" +
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmMinute()) + ":00";

            Calendar caNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar caAlarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();

            caAlarmTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, alarmData.getTimeAlarmYear());
            caAlarmTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, alarmData.getTimeAlarmMonth());
            caAlarmTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, alarmData.getTimeAlarmDay());
            caAlarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmData.getTimeAlarmHour());
            caAlarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmData.getTimeAlarmMinute());

            if (caAlarmTime.after(caNow)) {
                //next date is from the alarm
                auxDate = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%04d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmYear()) + "-" +
                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmMonth()) + "-" +
                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmDay()) + " " +
                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmHour()) + ":" +
                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", alarmData.getTimeAlarmMinute()) + ":00";
            } else {
                //It needs to check when is the next possible alarm
                boolean foundNextDate = false;

                foundNextDateCycle:
                while (foundNextDate == false) {

                    if (Consts.FREQUENCY_WEEKLY == alarmData.getAlarmFrequency())
                        caAlarmTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
                    else if (Consts.FREQUENCY_MONTHLY == alarmData.getAlarmFrequency())
                        caAlarmTime.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                    else
                        caAlarmTime.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

                    try {
                        if (caAlarmTime.after(caNow))
                            foundNextDate = true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        break foundNextDateCycle;
                    }

                }


                auxDate = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%04d", caAlarmTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "-" +
                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", caAlarmTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +
                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", caAlarmTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + " " +
                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", caAlarmTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" +
                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", caAlarmTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + ":00";

            }

            auxDateComp = auxDate;
        }




        if("".equals(auxDateComp))
            return false;


        Calendar calendarNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendarBegin = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendarFisnish = Calendar.getInstance();


        int marginMinutes = 1; //1 minute of margin


        calendarBegin.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(GlobalFunctions.formateDateFromString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy", auxDateComp)));
        calendarBegin.set(Calendar.MONTH, (Integer.parseInt(GlobalFunctions.formateDateFromString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "MM", auxDateComp))) - 1);
        calendarBegin.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(GlobalFunctions.formateDateFromString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd", auxDateComp)));
        calendarBegin.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(GlobalFunctions.formateDateFromString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "HH", auxDateComp)));
        calendarBegin.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(GlobalFunctions.formateDateFromString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "mm", auxDateComp)));
        calendarBegin.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(GlobalFunctions.formateDateFromString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "ss", auxDateComp)));


        calendarFisnish = (Calendar) calendarBegin.clone();

        calendarBegin.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendarBegin.get(Calendar.MINUTE) - marginMinutes);
        calendarFisnish.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendarFisnish.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + marginMinutes);

        if (calendarNow.after(calendarBegin) && calendarNow.before(calendarFisnish)) {
            Log.e(GlobalFunctions.getTag(), "Gonna show alarm!");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e(GlobalFunctions.getTag(), "NOT Gonna show alarm!");
            return false;
        }


    } else{
        //alarmData or alertData are NULL
        return false;
    }

}
```

After this I also check if my array of received alarms, has values with the same Id, and then only show one of them (just to make sure that there's no leftovers)

I tried set the Hour 2 years later, and it's pretty fast (at least on my device)

Again, this is not a ideal solution, if someone would find a better solution, please post it

Answer (score 2):

You don't need multiple receivers to handle this. Do the following in:

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    //Handle the logics here.
    //This function is called every time alarm repeats.
    //So simply find out if you need an alarm right now and pop alarm.
}
```

**XML**

```
  <receiver android:name=".manager.alarm.AlarmReceiver"
         android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_TIME"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

The alarm receiver is called as per your interval or on date change etc... You can then detect what caused the alarm receiver to be triggered and just act on it. Using multiple receiver is just overkill for this purpose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know how I can know this... I used the setRepeating, where I only know when the alarm was created the first time... I can only know the hour that the alarm should be send, not the day... and if the alarm is repeating for a month, How can I know if the user advance 5 days or just 1?
I can make some calculations based on the alarm creation, and check if the time that the alarm was triggered, is in fact a possible valid alarm, but this could involve a lot of calculations if the alarm was first created a year or 2 ago...
Am I thinking this wrong?

Comment: Suppose I put an alarm for 2nd March 2016. Then I changed the system time to 2nd  March 2016. Then I expect the alarm to go off at the moment. So you don't require to perform complex calculations to change this behavior.  But make sure that alarm time can be manually changed by the user. Also the next alarm time should be displayed on ui.

Comment: I didn't understand your example...
Fix example, I have an alarm that was set 1 year ago, which repeats every day... and when I receive a call from `AlarmReceiver`, I only know when the alarm was first created, which it means I only know the date and the hour (of it's first creation)... Since the alarms should trigger every day at the same time, I can valid if the hour is within a valid alarm period.. but if the user changes the Time within that valid period, this process doesn't work.
If it's possible to validate the triggering alarm inside the receiver, what kind of conditions should I do?

Comment: inside the onReceive method put something like if(current time>alarm creation time+interval) then pop alarm

Comment: Thanks again for your response... but I don't think you understand what's the problem here (or maybe I'm seeing this wrong)

Has I told you, I have a alarm that repeats every day... so if the phone time is changed to the future, my receiver will receive all of the days from today to the future date (defined by the user).
In my receiver I can't know if the receiving alarm is from now, yesterday ou 2 days ago... because I can't know how much time has passed since the alarm was created and "now", at least using the  `setRepeating`method... that's why I need to know when the user changes the alarm

Answer (score 0):

we were facing the same issue resolved by removing unnecessary `intent-filters`

from receiver in android manifest file.